# how to include libraries in sonarqube analysis android

Tags: android, sonarqube, libraries

i'm trying to create a sonareQube repport but it's give me juste the code that i had write, my need is to genrate a rapport for all the application, including libraries

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
 apply plugin: 'jacoco-android'
 sonarqube {
    properties {
    property "sonar.projectName", "yassine"
    property "sonar.projectKey", "yassine"
    property "sonar.tests", ["src/test/java"]
    property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
    property "sonar.test.inclusions", "**/*Test*/**"
    property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
    property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
    property "sonar.exclusions", '**/*Test*/**,' +
            '*.json,' +
            '**/*test*/**,' +
            '**/.gradle/**,' +
            '**/R.class'
  }
  }
  jacoco {
       toolVersion = "0.1.4"
       reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports")
  }
```

i tried to read the documentation but there is no option for me or i can't find it because of mybad english.
if you can help me i will be thankful